# What do #@+ and #@- in PHP comment blocks mean?

Tags: php, documentation

I've seen several PHP files where there are some special characters at the beginning of a doc block.
It starts with `/**#@+ some doc-text */` and ends with `/**#@-*/`.

What do these symbols mean?

I found that this seems to be used in various PHP frameworks (Zend, phpseclib, Magento) but couldn't find an explanation.

Example:

```
/**#@+
 * Constants for keys of data array. Identical to the name of the getter in snake case
 */
const ID = 'id';
const CUSTOMER_ID = 'customer_id';
const REGION = 'region';
const REGION_ID = 'region_id';
const COUNTRY_ID = 'country_id';
const STREET = 'street';
const COMPANY = 'company';
const TELEPHONE = 'telephone';
const FAX = 'fax';
const POSTCODE = 'postcode';
const CITY = 'city';
const FIRSTNAME = 'firstname';
const LASTNAME = 'lastname';
const MIDDLENAME = 'middlename';
const PREFIX = 'prefix';
const SUFFIX = 'suffix';
const VAT_ID = 'vat_id';
const DEFAULT_BILLING = 'default_billing';
const DEFAULT_SHIPPING = 'default_shipping';
/**#@-*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are used for [DocBlock templates (see Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#DocBlock_Templates).

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this in the wordpress config template.

It is a way to reduce maintaining duplicate comments on related items when doing phpdoc comments.  It is a feature of the `phpDocumentor` tool and there isn't really a spec although there are some proposed spec documents floating around for phpdoc (those proposals don't mention this functionality).

Using these starting/ending patterns tells `phpDocumentor` to apply this phpdoc comment to **all** items between the start and end markers.

```
/**#@+
 * documentation comment for "stuff"
 */
...multiple of the same thing to document...

/**#@-*/
```

The only documentation I could find was at [manual.phpdoc.org](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.docblocktemplate).
docs.phpdoc.org doesn't appear to have any reference to this functionality for whatever reason.

The wiki page linked in the answer from ArSeN was edited to remove most of the copy/pasted documentation in Oct 2018.  Here is a link to the historical version of the page before it was removed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=PHPDoc&oldid=863927054#DocBlock_Templates